# JS Quadratic Curve

Tags: javascript, graph, coordinates, quadratic

So far I've been able to make a straight line graph sort of thing using circles and assigning to them a random x coordinate, and setting y equal to x. This worked.

The trouble I'm having is with Math.pow() to do powers of x. It doesn't seem to be working. The circles don't appear anywhere, but the screen doesn't even get stretched (which is what I'd expect to happen if shapes go outside the boundaries).

```
var rangeCX = Math.round(Math.random() * 500);

var resultCX = rangeCX;
var resultCY = Math.pow(rangeCX,2);

circle.setAttribute("cx",resultCX);
circle.setAttribute("cy",resultCY);
```

I'm using SVG to display the circles.

Comment: Try putting your code in JSFiddle.

Comment: Wouldn't that make your average y-value around 62,500?  That might explain why they aren't appearing on your screen.  (Unless you have quite some monitor!)

Comment: Does it work for small values of rangeCX, like 1 or 2?  Try changing line 1 to `var rangeCX = 2;`, see if you get a plot.

Comment: Haha yes Scott, that monitor would be a health hazard!

Comment: OK. The problem was I was using a constant after "* 500". But you guys were still correct, so if you want to reply then I can mark as answered.